# CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies filtering

Tags: msbuild, nuget, nuget-package, asp.net-core-2.0

CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies (set in true) copes perfectly with the copying of nuget dependencies *.dll to the output folder. But there are many redundant libraries (Microsoft, System etc...) after build. I need some sort of a filtering to handle this mess. Is there elegant solution to solve the problem or only workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

If the libraries are truly redundant, they would not be copied to the output. Many System.* and Microsoft.* libraries are really needed, especially if you get newer versions from NuGet than are in the framework you are running on (e.g. .NET Core 1.0 with dependencies on newer libraries).

If you really want to do this you can add the following to your csproj file to filter out an assembly:

```
<Target Name="FilterCopyLocalItems" AfterTargets="ResolveLockFileCopyLocalProjectDeps">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Remove="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(Filename)' == 'Newtonsoft.Json'" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

You can use any MSBuild condition here, e.g. string methods:

```
Condition="$([System.String]::Copy('%(Filename)').Contains('HttpSys'))"
```

Comment: Ok, but I don't need them for my purpose, that's why I am asking about filtering.

Comment: Then you'd need to remove the NuGet packages. If they aren't copied locally, they are still used from the NuGet cache.